# How to get rid of ID inside RefinableString100 in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search

[image]

How do I get rid of long ID tag but want to leave Policy bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mapping the `RefinableString100` to `ows_taxId_InternalFieldName` or `ows_q_fieldname`, map it `ows_InternalFieldName`. Start the full crawl again. Once it successfully over, this field will automatically provide the correct value, in your case `Policy`.